# Looping Sounds in Samsung Smart TV Without Large Pause

Tags: javascript, html, audio, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to loop a 7.110 second audio clip in HTML5 using the Samsung Smart TV SDK. I'm running it through VirtualBox on SDK version 5.0.

When I play the sound with `mySound.play()` there is a small pause between `.play()` being called and the sound actually playing. Presumably this is due to the sound being downloaded, but the sound has already been downloaded by doing `mySound.src = "soundFile.wav"` earlier in the file.

Also when I try to play the sound again if `.play()` is called while the sound is still playing then nothing happens, and if `.play()` is called while the sound isn't playing then it pauses again (presumably to reload the sound for some reason).

I have tried adding the sound as a DOM element to the page but could not get it to loop, have tried using `addEventListener("ended"...)` which still caused huge gaps in playback and I've tried using `setInterval(function(){ mySound.play(); }, mySound.duration*1000)` which has left me with the same problem.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Cheers,
Harry

Comment: a few thoughts: 1. it could be virtulization lag and real TVs work fine. 2. there could be silence at the start of the audio, which setting currentPosition before play() will help. 3. you can mute the tag, call play(), then call pause() and unmute to get it ready for next time.

Comment: Hi dandavis, thanks for you reply. I've tried setting currentTime (haven't seen currentPosition before) but to no avail. And I'd much rather not get a tag working, but I guess one way I could do it is to have two tags and whilst one is loading the other is playing, but that seems like a huge workaround for what should be quite a simple thing to solve!

Comment: i meant currentTime, dan need more coffee...